# .groupby not working locally in visualstudiocode but working in jupyterlab

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to do a groupby locally in Visual Studio Code (I have anaconda installed), I get the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'groupby'`. When I try to run the same code in the JupyterLab environment provided by my school it works perfectly? Why is that? Anaconda appears to be up to date.

The groupby I'm trying to run that gives me the error in Visual Studio Code:

```
dataset.groupby('item_name')['quantity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: probably you imported something in the JupyterLab that is still being loaded, while the same was not loaded in VS. For example, in Jupyter add a block where you just import a library, run it, write other codes, remove the import line and keep editing the rest of the book. It will work. Do the same in VS, without the import statement it will fail. Doublecheck everything and **post a minimal portion of code reproducing the issue**

Comment: looks like your not working with a dataframe but rather an object already grouped.I don't think your code is identical in both enviroments.